# How do I achieve the functionality shown in the image below?

Tags: css, sass

[image: The need]

I am following the below example with flex box, but it does not completely fit my requirements

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/dpallagolla/pezwkzro/).

Case 1: left > Right

Case 2: left and right are almost equal and fill the space available

Case 3: left and right are lesser than the space available

case 4: left < right

In all the above cases, if left >> right, it consumes the entire width of the box and 'right' is not shown at all.

As shown below.

[image: The problem]

Question 1: How do I set a minimum width to the 'left' and 'right' divs so that they are not out of view.

Question 2: when left and right require more than allocated space, both have to occupy 50% width and get truncated with ellipsis.

HTML:

```
    <div id='parent5' class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
<div id='parent5' class="parent">
  <div class="left">Lefkjasdkjsadkjhdkjsahdklksajdlksajsahdhkjsahdkjsahdkjsat</div>
  <div class="right">Rikjsadkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdksaght</div>
</div>
<div id='parent5' class="parent">
  <div class="left">Leaskjdkjsahdkjsahdkjsadkjhdsakjhdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjhdkjsahdkjsaft</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
<div id='parent5' class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Rikjhsakjhdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjhsakjhdkjsahdjsadght</div>
</div>
<div id='parent5' class="parent">
  <div class="left">Lefsakdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdksadkjsadkjsadkjsahdsakhdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjsahdkjsakjsahdsat</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .left {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    text-align: left;
}

.right {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    text-align: right;    
}

.parent {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 1em 0;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    align-items: center;
}

#parent5 {
    > div {
        flex: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for tables! ;-)

Comment: is there a way to do it without using tables?

Comment: Use CSS to make it behave like tables (instead of flexbox).

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust both flex-shrink and min-width to get your result:

```css
.left {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  text-align: left;
}
.right {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  text-align: right;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1em 0;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  align-items: center;
}
.parent div {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-width: 100px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent1' class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
<div id='parent2' class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
<div id='parent3' class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long</div>
</div>
<div id='parent4' class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long</div>
  <div class="right">Right long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long</div>
</div>
<div id='parent5' class="parent">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without using the min-width property?

I would want the 'left' text to be displayed full till it reaches 50% of the parent and then truncated with ellipsis, same applies for the right.

so basically if the left text is less than 100px, I would want the right to occupy that space.

Comment: If there is such solution, I haven't been able to find it ... Sorry !